# Matching most similar lists in 2 group of lists in python

Tags: python

I have 2 python lists, which contain inner lists. All inner lists have same number of elements. All inner lists consist of `0`s and `1`s.

```
a = [[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]]

b = [[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]]
```

I would like to match each inner list in `a` with an inner list most similar to it from `b`.
Most similar means: in an inner list in `a`, as many as possible element with same index value should be the same in an inner list from b .

I mean [1,1,1,0,1,0] is more similar to [1,0,1,0,1,0] than [1,1,1,1,1,0].

Each inner list from `a` should be matched to only 1 inner list from `b`.

`a` and `b` may have different number of inner lists.

Is there a library or function to achive this fast? In my problem a and b has over 500 inner lists, and each inner list has around 35 elements.

Comment: Define most similar?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I defined.

Comment: I would use some similarity measure for that, maybe mean square error or mean absolute error, iterate and where the value of MAE/MSE will be lowest the match is closest

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy to quickly xor two binary lists to get the differences between the two, then count the number of 1s in that list of differences. This is just a quick way to calculate the edit distance between to binary lists.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]]

b = [[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]]

def bindist(x, y):
    xors = np.bitwise_xor(x, y)
    return np.count_nonzero(xors)

for x in range(len(a)):
    best_index = 0
    best_dist = 9999999999999
    for y in range(len(b)):
        dist = bindist(a[x],b[y])
        if dist < best_dist:
            best_dist = dist
            best_index = y
    print("a", x, a[x])
    print("b", best_index, b[best_index])
    print("distance", best_dist)
```

That code allows more than one list in `a` to match a list from `b`, but you should be able to adapt it without much difficulty.